# String to JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have the below JSON object array which I get back from the server. However while the server sends back the response the data is enclosed in `""` and that then makes the javascript function thing this is a String and not an Array.

```
"[  
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885],
    [32.36743646734031,50.95189517586323],
    [32.35467638118774,50.95876163094135],
    [32.342494619322636,50.904516635824166],
    [32.36279664436138,50.90039676277729],
    [32.380194752587755,50.899023471761666],
    [32.3648265962154,50.91481631844135],
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885]
]"
```

I just need to get the String into an array and use a for loop to iterate in the set of elements in the array. However since it is being treated a string it is not possible to iterate using a for loop.

any help?

Comment: `JSON.parse` can be your friend...

Comment: How are you getting this JSON from server? Via ajax?

Comment: `var result = JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: That is not JSON, it is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to run this through [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which is supported by almost all the JavaScript parsers:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(`[  
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885],
    [32.36743646734031,50.95189517586323],
    [32.35467638118774,50.95876163094135],
    [32.342494619322636,50.904516635824166],
    [32.36279664436138,50.90039676277729],
    [32.380194752587755,50.899023471761666],
    [32.3648265962154,50.91481631844135],
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885]
]`));
```

Just beware that the JavaScript might not like having line-breaks in strings if you give them in source code. If the original string does have line-breaks, that's totally fine. That's why I have used a template literal here.

```js
// Say you have your string here.
var str = `[  
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885],
    [32.36743646734031,50.95189517586323],
    [32.35467638118774,50.95876163094135],
    [32.342494619322636,50.904516635824166],
    [32.36279664436138,50.90039676277729],
    [32.380194752587755,50.899023471761666],
    [32.3648265962154,50.91481631844135],
    [32.361346650846805,50.90932315437885]
]`;
// Convert to array.
var arr = JSON.parse(str);
// Loop throught the array.
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  console.log(arr[i]);
```